# Array is not getting updated by useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

```js
function App() {

  let [task, setTask] = useState('');
  let [taskList, updateTaskList]= useState([]);

  let updateList = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(task);
    updateTaskList([
      ...taskList,
      {text: task, id: Math.random()*1000}
    ]);
    console.log(taskList);  
  }


  return (
    <div className="App" >
      <div>
        <h3 className="heading">Task list</h3>
        <form onSubmit={updateList}>
          <input type="text" className="input-section"
            placeholder="Enter your tasks" value={task}
            onChange={(event) => { setTask(event.target.value) }} />
          <span className="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </form>
         {/* {taskList.map((eachValue) => (
            <AddList listItem={eachValue} />
          ))};  */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the piece of my code, I am trying to create a to-do list here. But the updateTaskList is not working properly. After we enter some value in the input box, and press enter the taskList is showing empty array. I don't understand what I am doing wrong, can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: state is updated asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateTaskList` is asynchronous. It is probably updating your list, but you cannot see it because you immediately print the list after `updateTaskList`. Try adding a delay and then print task list or use `useEffect` to print it.

```
    setTimeout(() => console.log(taskList), 500)
```

OR

```
    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(taskList)
    }, [taskList.length])
```

Comment: i did what you suggested but i got this error "The final argument passed to useEffect changed size between renders. The order and size of this array must remain constant"

Comment: Change it from `taskList.length` to `taskList`, because the update function will set a new array to `taskList` and the comparator will trigger because the new array has a different reference

Comment: It would still work since you are just adding to the list, which will also change its length along with the reference. Regarding the error, the issue might be something else and not useEffect, it should have ideally worked.